# Truncating Y-Axis Title in Highcharts v4.1.5

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm currently having an issue where charts that are smaller in height but have long y-axis titles just start clipping at the edges (top and bottom).

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lce6cv9/2/)

I've tried using the [`style`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.title.style) option to try and enforce an ellipsis overflow.

```
yAxis : {
            title: {
                text:"Really really long title text that will go off the chart haha haha and so on and so on",
                style: {
                    textOverflow:'ellipsis',
                    overflow:'hidden'
                }
            }
        },
```

However, these sorts of things do not work without a maximum width of some sort, so I tried adding `width: '100%'` (see demo) but it stops short. I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that it's rotated.

Is there a way to have the title dynamically adjust to the height of the chart and properly truncate itself rather than just slide off into oblivion?

I haven't found anything helpful [in the documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.title). Also my Google-jitsu hasn't been able to locate any helpful or relevant topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using an absolute width, not a percent:

```
width: $('#container')[0].clientHeight*0.85,
```

Or even just:

```
width: 180,
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lce6cv9/3/)

Comment: +1 I actually really like the first idea. Not sure how the second idea fits into having it be dynamic at all, but the first one can work as long as the chart is re-rendered on resize.

Comment: It depends on how your application is implemented. In my case, I use PHP to set both values of width and div height, so I could easily chose appropriate values without having to use my first idea.